# shopify storefront api doesn't show filter results as expected

Tags: graphql, postman, shopify, shopify-storefront-api

I'm building an app using `shopify Storefront api`. So far I'm able to fetch products, collections. But when I try to filter the products in a collection it is not returning results as expected. Here is what i'm trying in postman

```
{
  collection(id:"Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Db2xsZWN // collection id"){
    products(first:10, filters:[{productVendor:"ADDIDAS"}]){
      edges{
        node{
            id
            title
            description
            productType
            vendor
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But i'm getting results that have vendor of NIKE and other types. Do i need to change something?
But when i try filter using `price` it works fine but when i try filtering using `productType` it is giving me not expected results. Am i doing something wrong?
Please help here

[image]

Comment: It is clearly a bug... I'll report

Comment: I've submitted a bug similar to this on Shopify's Storefront API feedback repo here https://github.com/Shopify/storefront-api-feedback/discussions/120